# How to change the content of rendered layout in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have to render the form that already exist in the project inside the page, but with a different title

```
app/views/welcome

<div class="form-wrapper>
  <%= render 'form/form_variants/register_1', register: @register %>
</div>

-----------

app/views/form/form_variants/register_1
<%= form_for register.user, as: :user, url: register_path(service: params[:service]), method: :post %>

 <%= content_tag :div, class: html_class('simpleFormHeading') do %>
   <%= content_tag :h1, t('signup.title_register') %> #title that should be changed
   <%= content_tag :p, raw(t('login.account_login.text', login_link: login_link)) %>
 <% end %>

#a lot of inputs

<% end%>
```

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass it as another variable to the partial

```
<div class="form-wrapper>
    <%= render 'form/form_variants/register_1', register: @register, signup_title = 'whatever' %>
</div>

# app/views/form/form_variants/register_1 
 # optional: init signup_title to a default value depending on your needs
 <% signup_title ||= t('signup.title_register') %>
 <%= content_tag :h1, signup_title %>
```